# Ruby gem geokit and :within maximum or tolerance?

Tags: ruby, geokit

Just started playing with [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/index.html) and trying some things out...

Things are pretty much working as expected, given a point, its finding things nearby.

However, if I set :within to be a large value, say 100,000, using :miles, I would expect to get most (if not all) of the objects in the db returned - but it seems to stop at a certain point - as if there is a built in maximum for :within.

I have tried the formulas :flat and :sphere.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't appear to be a built in maximum for `:within` but the lack of a limit (and sanity checking inside geokit).

It looks like a `:within` query ends up going through `Geokit::Bounds.from_point_and_radius` to produce a bounding box. `from_point_and_radius` will do a bit of trigonometry (see `endpoint` in `mappable.rb`) and the result will be an `Geokit::Bounds` instance.

I suspect that things are going wrong for you in the trigonometry; trig functions are periodic so your 100 000 radius will end up wrapping around to something between 0 and ~40 000 km (the Earth's circumference, ~25 000 miles) and the bounding box will not bound 100 000 miles. If you play with your 100 000 a bit you could probably get geokit to produce a bounding box that is only a couple centimeters per side (or a zero radius if you can sort out the usual floating point issues).

Executive summary: if you want them all, don't use `:within` at all; if you want to use `:within`, then give it a sensible distance (i.e. small enough to fit on the planet's surface without wrap around).

Comment: Thanks - think I go with the "sensible" within value option :)

Comment: Geokit only works on Earth? Just another example of how Rails doesn't scale.